# Use zip operation in a more efficient way on a dataset in Python

Tags: python-3.x, performance, dataset, apply

I do this operation below to this dataset:

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'id':      ["007",  "007", "001", "001", "008", "008", "007", "007", "009", "007", "000", "001", "009", "009", "009"], 
     'id_2': ["b",   "b",   "b",   "b",   "b",   "b",   "b",   "b", "b",   "b",   "b",
                       "c", "c", "c", "c"], 
     'userid':         ["us1", "us2", "us1", "us2", "us4", "us4", "us5", "us1", "us2", "us1", "us2", "us4", "us1", "us2", "us1"],
     "timestamp_date": [1589175687010,    1589188715313,      1589187142475,     1589187315368,      1589187155446,   1589187301028,     1589189765216,      1589190375088,
                        1589364060781,    1589421612029,      1589363453544,     1589364557808,      1589354347548,   1589356096273,     1589273208050]})



df = d.sort_values('timestamp_date')

df.groupby(['id_2', 'id'], sort=False).apply(
            lambda x: list(zip(x['userid'][:-1], x['userid'][1:],
                               x['timestamp_date'][:-1], x['timestamp_date'][1:]))).reset_index(name='duplicates')
```

But the problem is that this operation is taking super long. Just to give an idea, for 4 million registers, it is taking around 17 minutes.

I would like to know if there is any other way that I can do it that is more efficient. I think the zip is the problem for my tests and for what I've read online, but I couldn't find another way of doing and achieving the same result.

Comment: What is `df` ? `d` or `df_timeline` ?

Comment: Sorry, yes, df_timeline == df, i have updated the question